# PhP upload progress under PhP 5.3. Any approach to getting around the version limitation?

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload, jquery-file-upload

I want to write a simple custom file upload progress code in a PhP, JQuery environment. My server host runs only PhP 5.2 or 5.3. The following is not supported:  http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.upload-progress.php. It requires PhP 5.4. Yes, I am on Godaddy shared web hosting.

My question is, how to get around this. Surely file upload progress bars existed before 5.4. I do not want to invest time in something outdated either.  I would prefer writing raw code myself, instead, but only if required. I was thinking of writing code to manually check the file sizes of the temporary files and use it in the progress bars. Since that would be low-level coding, it should run on any version of PhP.  Is this a good and feasible approach? Or there are better ways. Please reply.

Comment: The trick of scanning the temporary directory is possibly the simplest one. Other solutions are based on third-party PHP extensions or completely skipping PHP for the upload part (e.g., using a CGI script written in another language) and have further requirements.

Comment: Also before 5.4 you can get a upload progress via APC simple example here http://www.johnboy.com/php-upload-progress-bar/

Comment: is that not possible to update it to required verion of php( without FastCGI.)in case of shared hosting on your server ?

Comment: Use ajax upload http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: @Kannan. I have looked into the blueimp solution. It is too bloated for my needs and I need to customize a few things. Also, I found that it relies on HTML5 "multiple" attribute. May be not. Other issues too.

Comment: Álvaro G. Vicario. Thanks. Those are encouraging words as I expressed the same approach.

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario. Let me see if Godaddy has APC...

Comment: Can anyone suggest if the "APC" approach would be better and easier then writing code to check status of temp files? I have no idea of what the APC approach entails. Will look into it. But any suggestions on whether the check-temp-file-status is better approach or not would help.

Comment: Temp files are nothing but a guess (there's really no way to know what file belongs to what upload). APC implements the feature properly.

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario. I am aware of that but I believe that the $_FILES array has names of temp files for each file. This can be saved in a session variable and another AJAX call, from the same session, which has the key to locate the temp file names, can keep monitoring the progress of these files. I think it should work. I will be working on it tomorrow.

Comment: @Samir Once your script starts running and `$_FILES` becomes available, your upload has already finished. That's why you need built-in support or witty hacks in the first place.

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario. Very good observation and I was thinking about it but the key is will the $_FILES content still be good to give the names of the tmp files generated, even after the upload, UNTIL the move to the real file names is done expressly in the main upload program. I think yes. I will make the main upload program wait until the monitoring program has started reading the status of the tmp files status.  The monitoring program is another AJAX call to another PhP program but using the same session so session variables can be used for IPC and passing tmp file names. It should work?

Comment: What's the point of displaying the upload status when there're 20ms left? It'll only show: 0%, 99.99%, 100%.

Comment: @Alvaro G. Vicario.  The upload status is truly useful for big files. The boundary condition if it is a small upload has to be handled too, correctly. Thats what this approach will handle. The upload bar will progress in one step to the end in small file uploads. Thats ok. It is instantaneous anyway. Its the big file uploads that will be handled properly. Remember the monitoring program keeps sending back status until uploads are done. The main upload program waits to exit only until monitoring program starts, not until upload is done. This wait will be there only for small files.  comment?

Comment: @Alvaro G. Vicario. After trying I realized now. The $_FILES info is post-upload 100%. Of no use. Thanks...